# Combining Picturefill 2.1 with any lazyload plugin

Tags: responsive-design, lazy-loading, picturefill

I'm trying to combine Picturefill 2.1 with any available lazy load plugin, but I had no success yet. Most of the code I found on Google is for Picturefill 1.

Does anyone here has done this before and could help me? Picturefill is working just fine, the problem is the lazy load part because I don't have the images width and height, which causes all images to be loaded at once.

Comment: Take a look at the answers here, that should satisfy you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507164/is-there-a-way-to-combine-the-lazyload-js-library-with-picturefill

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't need to support IE8:
use [lazysizes - responsive image lazy laoder](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes)